# Batch import through the REST API for neo4j

Tags: import, neo4j, batch-processing

I am using neo4j's rest api for batch importing.

As per the docs ( http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html )

> This service is transactional. If any of the operations performed fails (returns a non-2xx HTTP status code), the transaction will be rolled back and all changes will be undone.

I am imporitng 60K nodes and 200K relationships.  (At least) One of the relationships fails and as expected the whole operation fails.

**My question is, is there way to track which specific line of the import is failing so that I can isolate or remove it?**

---

Update:  As per @Thomas Fenzi's answer below, I turned on the `X-Stream` flag, however it is moving at a snails pace.  (about 1/5 th the speed).   Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the API in streaming mode (chapter 18.15.3. in the docs, send a `X-Stream = true` header and do whatever you need client side to handle chunked responses) you get responses up to the point of error.

60k nodes and 200k relationships might be a bit high for a single transaction, depending on your hardware.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into that.    In general, the size of the data does not seem to cause any issues